# Database table values did not output

Tags: php

```
   <table border="2">
                   <tr>
                      <th>Memeber Id</th>
                      <th>Lastname</th>
                      <th>Firstname</th>
                      <th>Birthdate</th>
                      <th>Gender</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                      <th>Dedication Date</th>
                      <th>Acceptance Date</th>
                      <th>Baptism Date</th>
                      <th>Mother</th>
                      <th>Father</th>
                      <th>Decription</th>
                    </tr>    

            <?php
                  $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
                  $er = mysql_select_db("memberdb");
                  $query = "insert into memberinformation values('$memberid','$lastname','$firstname','$birthdate','$gender','$status','$dedicationdate'
                    ,'$acceptancedate','$baptismdate','$mother','$father','$description')";
                  $result = mysql_query($query);
                  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM memberinformation");

                  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                    {
                        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                        //you need to exit the script, if there is an error
                        exit();
                    } 

                    while ($array = mysql_fetch_row($result));
                    {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['memberid'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['birthdate'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['dedicationdate'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['acceptancedate'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['baptismdate'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['mother'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['father'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";

                        echo "<script> alert('Tama ka.'); </script>";
                    }

                    echo "</table>";

                    mysql_close($con);
            ?>
```

I have a problem because the code does not output what I am expecting. It should output the data from memberinformation table from the member database. Please help me if there is some lacking lines in this code or I have some mistakes.

Comment: First: where are you getting the variables you're inserting from? Second: you're using both mysql and mysqli..? Third: what's the output? Provide us more informations

Comment: Yes, NEVER EVER mix mysql and mysqli. And you say you get output you don't expect. But WHAT output do you get? Tell us more, so we can help you, we are no wizards (not all of us).

Comment: `$array` and `$row` aren't the same, and the semi-colon at the end of `mysql_fetch_row($result));` also causes issues. **Enabling error reporting** probably would have given you these answers.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the value $row, while the data is in $array:

```
while ($array = mysql_fetch_row($result));
...
echo "<td>" . $row['memberid'] . "</td>";
```

This should work:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
...
echo "<td>" . $row['memberid'] . "</td>";
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You mixed up MySQL and MySQLi libraries.

Replace `mysqli_connect_errno()` with `mysql_errno()` to use MySQL library. (also for `mysqli_connect_error()`)

But it's very important that you shouldn't use deprecated MySQL library (`mysql_*` functions). Replace it with MySQLi and PDO instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have `$array = mysql_fetch_row($result)` but in table you are printing e.g. $row['memberid'] instead of `$array['memberid']`. I believe that will be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

change $array = mysql_fetch_row($result) in to $row = mysql_fetch_row($result)

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, stop using `mysql_` functions
- Second, you're mixing API's (`mysql_` and `mysqli_`). Choose `mysqli_*` instead.
- Third, it should be `$row = mysql_fetch_row($result)`
- Fourth, as much as possible use parameterized queries / prepared statements
- Fifth, always turn on error reporting

Example:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'memberdb');
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM memberinformation');
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    echo "<script> alert('May Mali Ka.');</script>";
    //you need to exit the script, if there is an error
    exit();
}

$stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO memberinformation VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssss', $memberid,$lastname,$firstname,$birthdate,$gender,$status,$dedicationdate,$acceptancedate,$baptismdate,$mother,$father,$description);
$stmt->execute();

?>
<style>table, tr, td {border: 1px solid black;}</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Memeber Id</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Birthdate</th><th>Gender</th><th>Status</th><th>Dedication Date</th>
        <th>Acceptance Date</th><th>Baptism Date</th><th>Mother</th><th>Father</th><th>Decription</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['birthdate']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['dedicationdate']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['acceptancedate']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['baptismdate']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['mother']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['father']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: *sidenote:* do not use `border="2"`; use CSS instead

Comment: @Raptor haha actually i didn't notice i put two in there, yeah of course css is way way better against attribute border